# Error installing boot features of karaf in kettle

Tags: osgi, pentaho, kettle, karaf

I am trying to integrate kettle and the big data plugin into my project. 
when the karaf of kettle loads the plugin named pdi-osgi-bridge-activator. it throws an exception :

```
2018-09-01 16:52:09.303 DEBUG 9236 --- [      Thread-52] o.a.k.f.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl     : Starting bundle: pdi-osgi-bridge-activator
2018-09-01 16:52:09.365 ERROR 9236 --- [      Thread-52] o.a.k.f.internal.BootFeaturesInstaller   : Error installing boot features

java.lang.Exception: Could not start bundle wrap:mvn:pentaho/pdi-osgi-bridge-activator/7.1.0.0-12 in feature(s) pentaho-base-1.0: Unresolved constraint in bundle pdi-osgi-bridge-activator [60]: Unable to resolve 60.0: missing requirement [60.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.pentaho.di.core.exception)
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.startBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:504) ~[3.0.3:na]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:459) ~[3.0.3:na]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.BootFeaturesInstaller.installBootFeatures(BootFeaturesInstaller.java:92) ~[3.0.3:na]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.BootFeaturesInstaller$1.run(BootFeaturesInstaller.java:71) [3.0.3:na]
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle pdi-osgi-bridge-activator [60]: Unable to resolve 60.0: missing requirement [60.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.pentaho.di.core.exception)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974) ~[org.apache.felix.main-4.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037) ~[org.apache.felix.main-4.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955) ~[org.apache.felix.main-4.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942) ~[org.apache.felix.main-4.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.startBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:501) ~[3.0.3:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

i know the class:

org.pentaho.osgi.legacy.LegacyPluginExtenderFactory

uses

org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettlePluginException

but these is nothing happen if i start kettle by Spoon.bat.
do i miss some arguments or configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Which bundle has "org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettlePluginException"?

It need some bundle to export it.